# SQLite query with GROUP BY and CASE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

In a SQLite DB I have the following data structure in the table `items` (simplified for sake of clarity):

| id | storeId | archived |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a-1 | 0 |
| 2 | a-1 | 1 |
| 3 | a-1 | 1 |
| 4 | b-1 | 0 |
| 5 | b-1 | 0 |
| 6 | b-1 | 0 |
| 7 | b-1 | 0 |
| 8 | b-1 | 1 |

I'd like to select all items that have been archived (`archived = 1`), and group by `storeId` those that have not been archived.

To do so, I've written this query:

```
const queryString = `
  SELECT *
  FROM items
  GROUP BY 
    CASE
      WHEN items.archived = 1  
        THEN items.id
      ELSE IFNULL(storeId, id)
    END
`;
```

My issue is that the non archived items with a `storeId` for which there are archived items are never displayed. They seem to be grouped with the archived items with the same `storeId` value.

In other terms, with that query and that data, I only get the following:

| id | storeId | archived |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a-1 | 1 |
| 3 | a-1 | 1 |
| 8 | b-1 | 1 |

I guess I am missing something of how the GROUP BY works. How can I achieve my intended result?

Comment: Also specify the expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, the answer was grouping by multiple columns, with concatenation:

```
const queryString = `
  SELECT items.*, items.storeId || ' ' || items.archived AS concatenatedValues
  FROM items
  GROUP BY 
    CASE
      WHEN items.archived = 1 THEN items.id
      ELSE concatenatedValues
    END
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the row with the min `id` for the `storeId`s with `archived = 0`, then you can do it with `MIN()` window function in a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       CASE 
         WHEN archived THEN id
         ELSE MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY storeId)
       END AS id,
       storeId,
       archived
FROM items;
```

Or, if `archived = 0` (if it exists) is not always the first in each `storeId`, use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       CASE 
         WHEN archived THEN id
         ELSE FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY storeId, archived ORDER BY id)
       END AS id,
       storeId,
       archived
FROM items;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SQ_WXJhN).